# How do I annotate rust variables' data type without assignment?

Tags: types, rust, variable-assignment

I'm new to rust, and I'd like to declare a typed variable without initializing it. Is this possible in Rust? If so, is it advisable or are there better, more rustacean-y ways to do it?

I'm looking at the following code from [rustlings](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings) which fails to compile because it can't infer the type of x:

```rust
    let x;
    if x == 10 {
        println!("Ten!");
    }
```

So, I tried this:

```rust
let x: i32;
```

however, now the compiler will throw an error on the comparison line saying that x hadn't been declared.

This works fine, but I was left wondering if one can declare the type without an assignment.

```rust
let x: i32 = 10;
```

Or is the correct way to do it involve designing your code to avoid such situations in the first place? I come from a C background and I'm probably a little too comfortable with being lazy with types.

Comment: You can declare a variable (and its type) without initialisation, but the Rust compiler (correctly) prevents you from ever reading its value before it's been initialized. See [https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/checked-uninit.html](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/checked-uninit.html)

Comment: Also, in general the "declare first before using" pattern prevalent since the days of C/C++ aren't preferred anymore with modern languages. Instead, it's considered best practice to declare variables closest to where they're used. See [https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/variable_bindings/declare.html](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/variable_bindings/declare.html)

Comment: Technically you can do something like `let x = unsafe { mem::uninitialized::<i32>() }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rust, the type of a variable is usually inferred from the context.
The context can include any of the following:

- The type of the value being assigned:

```rust
let x = String::new(); //x is now a String
```

- The return type of the function being called:

```rust
fn foo() -> usize {
    40
}
let x = foo(); //x is now usize
```

But if you don't have a type to infer, as in there is no assignment to the variable:

```rust
let x;
```

Then rust cannot infer the type. Therefore, [it will get mad at you](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35386903b1c1f879cbd947ca5abae3f5).

Another problem that needs to be addressed in this answer; the fact that rust doesn't allow the reading of uninitialized variables. The following value, `x` is uninitialized:

```
let x: u32;
```

Reading the value of an uninitialized `u32` probably wouldn't do too much, but consider the following:

```
struct MyString {
    ptr: *const u8,
    len: usize,
    cap: usize,
}
```

If we were to provide a safe wrapper around this, this would be perfectly fine, after all, this is essentially what the [stdlib `String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#283-285) boils down to. But, if we were to own an uninitialized `MyString` and tried to read its contents, we'd end up reading a garbage address from the `ptr`, and a garbage `len` and `cap`. This would lead to reading a garbage pointer, which is undefined behavior, which is rust's #1 priority to eliminate.

So, to recap:
✓ Every variable must have a type determinable at runtime (Including erased types, because those are concrete types too [`dyn Trait` and [`impl Trait`](https://medium.com/@iopguy/impl-trait-in-rust-explanation-efde0d94946a)], but `impl Trait` is special.)
✓ Every variable must be assigned some kind of value before you can read its value.
✓ Rust tries very hard to eliminate **all** undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, provided that the compiler can see that it will always have a value assigned before you try to read from it, and it will only ever be assigned once. This can be helpful in peculiar circumstances. Here's [a slightly contrived example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=571d3bb2c917465ac5d8365437d1255b).

```rust
fn main() {
    let some_cond = false;

    let x;
    let y;
    let z: u8;

    if some_cond {
        x = 1;
        y = 2;
        z = 3;
    } else {
        x = 4;
        y = 5;
        z = 6;
    }

    println!("x = {}", x); // "x = 4"
    println!("y = {}", y); // "y = 5"
    println!("z - 10 = {}", z.wrapping_sub(10)); // "z - 10 = 252"
}
```